# Замена виджета одного класса на виджет другого класса Pyqt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Я хочу заменить виджет одного класса на виджет другого класса. 
То есть
удалить все объекты виджета `centralwidget1`
и объявить все объекты виджета `centralwidget2` в виджете `centralwidget1`.

Я попробовал обратиться к классу `Ui_MainWindow2` к виджету `centralwidget2` и объявить все объекты виджета `centralwidget2` в виджете `centralwidget1`, также я попробовал наследовать виджет

У меня вышло создать новое окно и закрыть старое. Также это можно сделать меняя содержимое самих объектов, но я хочу всю логику прописывать в одном классе и наследовать от остальных классов виджеты.

То как это должно выглядеть :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код :

```
class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow1):
        MainWindow1.setObjectName("MainWindow1")
        MainWindow1.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow1)
        self.centralwidget1.setObjectName("centralwidget1")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget1)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget1)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(172, 118, 56, 17))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        MainWindow1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget1)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow1)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow1", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow1", "Кнопка 1"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow1", "Окно 1"))


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow2):
        MainWindow2.setObjectName("MainWindow2")
        MainWindow2.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow2)
        self.centralwidget2.setObjectName("centralwidget2")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget2)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget2)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(172, 118, 56, 17))
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        MainWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget2)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow2", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "Кнопка 2"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "Окно 2"))


class Ui_MainWindow3(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow3):
        MainWindow3.setObjectName("MainWindow3")
        MainWindow3.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow3)
        self.centralwidget3.setObjectName("centralwidget3")
        self.pushButton3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget3)
        self.pushButton3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton3.setObjectName("pushButton3")
        MainWindow3.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget3)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow3)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow3.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow3", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton3.setText(_translate("MainWindow3", "Кнопка 3"))


class MainWindow3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent


class MainWindow2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent

        self.window3 = MainWindow3(self)

        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.create_win3)

    def create_win3(self):
        self.hide()
        self.window3.show()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):
    def __init__(self):# --- (self, centralwidget2) < --- хотел попробовать унаследовать виджет (centralwidget2) чтобы потом обявить в виждете (self.centralwidget1)
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.window2 = MainWindow2(self)

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.create_win2)

    def create_win2(self):
        self.hide()# --- self.centralwidget1.setHiden(True) < --- удалит все обьекты виджета (self.centralwidget1)
        self.window2.show()# --- Ui_MainWindow2.centralwidget2(self.centralwidget1) < --- хотел попробовать обратиться к виджету (centralwidget2) и обявить в виждете (self.centralwidget1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = MainWindow()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможный вариант решение вашей идеи, использовать виджет [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Класс `QStackedWidget` предоставляет стек виджетов, в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow1):
        MainWindow1.setObjectName("MainWindow1")
        MainWindow1.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow1)
        self.centralwidget1.setObjectName("centralwidget1")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget1)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget1)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(172, 118, 56, 17))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        MainWindow1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget1)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow1)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow1", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow1", "Кнопка 1"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow1", "Окно 1"))


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow2):
        MainWindow2.setObjectName("MainWindow2")
        MainWindow2.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow2)
        self.centralwidget2.setObjectName("centralwidget2")
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget2)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget2)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(172, 118, 56, 17))
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        MainWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget2)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow2", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "Кнопка 2"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow2", "Окно 2"))


class Ui_MainWindow3(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow3):
        MainWindow3.setObjectName("MainWindow3")
        MainWindow3.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow3)
        self.centralwidget3.setObjectName("centralwidget3")
        self.pushButton3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget3)
        self.pushButton3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 252, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton3.setObjectName("pushButton3")
        MainWindow3.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget3)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow3)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow3):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow3.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow3", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton3.setText(_translate("MainWindow3", "Кнопка 3"))


class MainWindow3(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow3):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.label = QLabel('Это 3-я страница', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ccbdff;') 
        self.pushButton3.setFixedSize(150, 40)
         
        layout.addWidget(self.label, stretch=1) 
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton3, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop) 
        
        layout_main = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget3)
        layout_main.addWidget(self.frame) 
        
        self.pushButton3.clicked.connect(
            lambda : self.parent.stacked.setCurrentIndex(0))    # на 1-ю страницу ?


class MainWindow2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent

        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.create_win3)

    def create_win3(self):
        self.parent.stacked.setCurrentIndex(2)


class MainWindow1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(
            lambda : self.parent.stacked.setCurrentIndex(1))
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stacked = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)

        self.window1 = MainWindow1(self)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window1)
        
        self.window2 = MainWindow2(self)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window2)
        
        self.window3 = MainWindow3(self)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.window3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что вы предложили сработало. Так что я ещё почитаю документацию, но хочу спросить я правильно понимаю что я могу внести виджеты в класс  ```QStackedWidget``` и при необходимости объявить определённый виджет ?

Comment: @assert, да, каждая страница - это отдельный виджет и  добавлять их в QStackedWidget вы можете сколько вам надо. Внутри каждой страницы вы рисуете все что вам надо, как например у меня на третьей странице.